# 404 when calling Web API v2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web Api controller which returns 404 when I call it.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public static string Test()
    {
        return "Hola!";
    }
}
```

Heres the Route Config

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And here's the Route Debugger info.
I get 404 for below requests

```
http://localhost:8081/api/values/test  
http://localhost:8081/api/values/get
```

[image: Route Debugger info]

Any ideas why its failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action is defined as a static method. Actions cannot be static.

```
[HttpGet]
public static string Test()
{
    return "Hola!";
}
```

Make it an instance method and your code will work.

```
[HttpGet]
public string Test()
{
    return "Hola!";
}
```